# IF Query Based on a Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I am working in a shipment report with a Power Query in Excel that contains Part Numbers and Descriptions. I would like to create a consolidated column that denotes the product line (called Product Line Description), in order to more easily filter Part Numbers (i.e. P/N ABC-123 and ABC-321 are both in the ABC product line). The new column would say "ABC" for both of these P/Ns.

Currently I have built a lengthy IF QUERY shown in the picture, but this is not that easy to send to my other colleagues who have their own shipment reports. I am wondering if there is an easier way to build this IF query so that I can send it to my colleagues and they can build it into their own spreadsheets.

I've whited out the P/Ns for my own/company privacy. One of the complications is that due to the P/N scheme it is sometimes easier to filter based on a phrase in the description, so the IF operator and the column used can vary in each ELSEIF clause in the version I created.

[Existing IF Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo9cJ.png)

Ultimately I transfer this whole data set over to a Pivot Table so that I can see shipment values by month.

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XSdF.png)

Any ideas to simplify this whole process would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just split on the hyphen or other transition setting off the product line?

Answer (score 0):

Potential ideas

(a) go to home ...advanced editor, copy the powerquery code and send that to someone to use on their own reports.

(b) create a powerquery template file that reads in the external shipment report, with the filepath to that report coming from a variable cell that gets filled in.  This can also be done for varying part numbers

(c) create a macro that can be saved on their excel instances that can be run to create the powerquery code and apply the filter and create the pivot